# Limit a filename character by the middle in PHP

Tags: php, replace, substring, ellipsis

I have a filename stored as `25507647_377205372719383_8438629006006905602_n.jpg` and would like it to be display as `255076...905602_n.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) for the win.

> substr_replace — Replace text within a portion of a string

Depending on your design logic, you can offer a positive or negative length parameter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GM7JA))

```
$file = "25507647_377205372719383_8438629006006905602_n.jpg";
echo substr_replace($file, '...', 6, 32);
echo "\n";
echo substr_replace($file, '...', 6, -12);
```

Output:

```
255076...905602_n.jpg
255076...905602_n.jpg
```

Comment: This provides the literal result for your sample input.  If you require a solution that is more dynamic, you will need to improve your question to explain the logic to the replacement.